# Device missing from lspci on one linux distribution but not the other???!! How and Why?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pci, antix

Everything I've read says that when the Linux Kernel boots up, PCI devices are scanned and should be in /sys/bus/pci.

I have two different Linux distributions, one shows a wireless device at 01:00.0, the other can't find it at all (not listed). The same driver is loaded on boot (ath5k).

Under what circumstance would a device NOT show up even using lspci -M?

Everybody I've talked to is convinced that can't be true, until I boot up on two different distress and literally SHOW them that on one it's there and the other, it's not.

BTW, the two distributions in question are Antix (nothing shown) and MX (does show). Also Knoppix will show the device as well.

Comment: Drivers or different `lspci` implementation? Try `ls -l $(which lspci)` on both nodes. Does one of them point to `busybox`?

Comment: Good idea but no, both are true lspci and not busybox. On the driver point, I thought that even if you don’t have a driver it’s going to get listed when you do lspci -M

Comment: I would say the difference between the two kernels is relevant, not the difference between lspci versions. Normally, something should be written to the kernel message buffer (`dmesg` to display it).